# audio.currentTime invalidStateError IE11, JS, HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I get this error in IE11, i have temporary changed all variables on just a number, but i can't get rid of this error.

```
audio.currentTime = 10;
```

The error looks like:

```
SCRIPT5022: InvalidStateError
```

This script works good in Chrome and Firefox.
According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it is should work.

Comment: Since IE doesn't really support anything properly, the fastest solution I came up with was putting a try/catch on my audio function. IE users shouldn't be allowed to have sound if they still use this browser...

Answer (score 23):

I know this question is old but I just encountered the same problem and wanted to post what I learned.

Did your audio player successfully load the audio?  If the src="#" or if you gave the player the wrong path to the audio file the line of code you provided will give the error you mentioned.

I would suggest trying the following code where audioPlayer is the id of the audio element to perform a simple check that the audio file has indeed loaded:

```
    if (!isNaN(aud.duration)) {
        aud.currentTime = vid.currentTime;
    }
```

But of course, if you're expecting the audio to have loaded, fix the path to the audio file

Answer (score 19):

In IE11, this error occurs while accessing the `currentTime` attribute of video before the meta data of video is loaded. So following code solved my error.

```
vidEl.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  vidEl.currentTime = someSeekTime;
}, false);
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: For typescript/react this worked fine. this.audioEl.onloadedData = function(): void { this.audioEl.currentTime = newTime; }.bind(this);

Comment: This saved me hours!

Comment: This saved me too with an Angular 7 app running in IE11. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that converting the Wav file to MP3 solved the issue for me. Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/20462684/5053952 prevented the error but the Wav file still would not play. Converting to MP3 solved the issue completely.

(IE11 on Win10)